# Mail can't be send: Relay access denied

Tags: ruby, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2

I have two ruby on rails application on different servers. Both are working fine, but one (server 2) can't send any mails.
I got always the **554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied** error.

On server 2 I tested the mail communication with the help of telnet and it works, but it doesn't works with the ruby on rails application.
Other application can send mails, too.

The only difference between both systems are the os (Debian 6 (server 1) and RHEL 6 (server 2)) and the ip ranges (10 network (server 2) and 53 network (server 1)).

I think the best way is to use a simple mail application, but I don't know, how to write something like that.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address of your second server is not in the whitelist for that email server, but the first one is.

Unless you're using authenticated SMTP, you will have to add the IP addresses of all your application servers to the whitelist configuration.

Using telnet will only tell you if the port is accepting connections, not if you can actually send email. For that you'll have to perform an actual SMTP transaction.

There are services like [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/), [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or even my start-up [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) which will act as a mail server for you.

Comment: The IP of server 2 is whitelisted, otherwise I couldn't create SMTP transaction over telnet. These mails were transmitted to the receivers. I edited my question for more clearance.

Comment: Did you connect and get the SMTP banner, or did you run through actually try to send a message using `HELO`, `MAIL FROM`, `RCPT TO` and `DATA`? The banner is always presented unless you're firewalled or the server is configured to reject connections, which is not the default. Try manually sending mail to an external account like GMail to verify it is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the external mail, that was the problem. It seems that there is a wrong security policy for the server 2. Over telnet I send only internal mails and over the application only external mails.